# Can't join multiple tables in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

the length is:

```
mysql> select count(*) from projects join(select project_skills.skill_id from project_skills where project_skills.skill_id = 7) as s on projects.id = s.skill_id;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|      869 |
+----------+
```

another length is:

```
mysql> select count(*) from projects join(select project_frameworks.framework_id from project_frameworks where project_frameworks.framework_id = 3) as f on projects.id = f.framework_id;     

+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|      264 |
+----------+
```

I need to combine these length(result).

So I came up:

```
select count(*) from projects join(select project_skills.skill_id from project_skills where project_skills.skill_id = 7) as s on projects.id = s.skill_id join(select project_frameworks.framework_id from project_frameworks where project_frameworks.framework_id = 3) as f on projects.id = f.framework_id;
```

But the length is `0`....

How can I reach my ideal?

■ Table Construction

projects vs project_skills(one to many)

skills vs project_skills(one to many)

projects vs project_frameworks(one to many)

frameworks vs project_frameworks(one to many)

project_skill（column：id、project_id、skill_id）

project_frameworks（column：id、project_id、framework_id）

Comment: *I need to combine these length(result).* ??? What do you mean? Union? Intersection? 2 separate values in a row? separate values in 2 rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sum it up using union all to get the total count.

```
SELECT sum(q.c) FROM (
select 
  count(*) as c
from 
  projects 
     join( select  project_skills.skill_id from project_skills where project_skills.skill_id = 7 ) as s 
     on projects.id = s.skill_id 
union all 
select 
  count(*) as c
from 
  projects 
  join( select project_frameworks.framework_id  from project_frameworks where project_frameworks.framework_id = 3 ) as f 
  on projects.id = f.framework_id
  ) q;
```

Comment: that' was helpful thank you!!